# add leading zeros to a list of numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, list, format, digits

I am new to Python. I am trying to adjust the format of a list which looks like below:

```
data=[1,10,313,4000,51234,123456]
```

and I would like to convert them to a list of strings with leading zeros:

```
result=['000001','000010','000313','004000','051234','123456']
```

each of the element has 6 digits.

I know for a single number X, I can do:

```
str(X).zfill(6)
```

but I am not sure how to apply this to a list. I would like to solve this problem without using a for loop.

Anyone could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Apply the same [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) function in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like this

```
>>> [str(item).zfill(6) for item in data]
['000001', '000010', '000313', '004000', '051234', '123456']
```

Alternatively, you can use the string's [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, with [format specifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), like this

```
>>> ["{:06d}".format(item) for item in data]
['000001', '000010', '000313', '004000', '051234', '123456']
```

If you are going to do the formatting more often, then you can store that in a variable, like this

```
>>> formatter = "{:06d}".format
>>> [formatter(item) for item in data]
['000001', '000010', '000313', '004000', '051234', '123456']
```

If you are using Python 2.x, then you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and the `formatter` function, like this

```
>>> map(formatter, data)
['000001', '000010', '000313', '004000', '051234', '123456']
```

If you are using Python 3.x, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterable `map` object. So, you need to explicitly create a list, like this

```
>>> list(map(formatter, data))
['000001', '000010', '000313', '004000', '051234', '123456']
```

Comment: To improve your answer, I'd fill to the maximum length in the list, rather than a hardcoded 6.

Comment: Learned something new today. Thanks!

Comment: @MalikBrahimi But OP wants `each of the element has 6 digits.`

Comment: @thefourtheye,Thanks for the quick answer. This is exactly what I am looking for.