# Python range of numbers with specific number of digits

Tags: python, list

I am looking to create a list of numbers from 1 to X (where X is >100). I know the range function is perfect for this. I will ultimately be using this list to develop a list of strings with a single string (i.e. ".pdf") appended to the end of each number. However, when I do this, I want to be sure that each "number" has three total digits. For example, instead of "5", I want "005", and the resultant string in my final list will be "005.pdf" (i.e. the number "005" appended to the string ".pdf").

I would simply add "00" to the beginning of each string, but that would not work for two-digit integers (which require the addition of a single "0") or three-digit integers (which do not require any additional "0").

Is there an efficient way to do this without manually iterating over 1-9 and 10-99 to correct the number of digits?

Thanks!

Example code:

```
string=".pdf"
max_num=500
numrange = range(1,max_num)
final_list = [str(x) + string for x in numrange]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add leading zeros to a list of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000613/add-leading-zeros-to-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.format` to add leading zeros. For examnple:

```py
out = ["{:03d}.pdf".format(n) for n in range(200)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['000.pdf', '001.pdf', '002.pdf', '003.pdf', '004.pdf', '005.pdf', '006.pdf', '007.pdf', '008.pdf', '009.pdf', '010.pdf', '011.pdf', '012.pdf', '013.pdf', '014.pdf', '015.pdf', '016.pdf', '017.pdf', '018.pdf', '019.pdf', '020.pdf', '021.pdf', '022.pdf', '023.pdf', '024.pdf', '025.pdf', '026.pdf', '027.pdf', '028.pdf', '029.pdf', '030.pdf', '031.pdf', '032.pdf', '033.pdf', '034.pdf', '035.pdf', '036.pdf', '037.pdf', '038.pdf', '039.pdf', '040.pdf', '041.pdf', '042.pdf', '043.pdf', '044.pdf', '045.pdf', '046.pdf', '047.pdf', '048.pdf', '049.pdf', '050.pdf', '051.pdf', '052.pdf', '053.pdf', '054.pdf', '055.pdf', '056.pdf', '057.pdf', '058.pdf', '059.pdf', '060.pdf', '061.pdf', '062.pdf', '063.pdf', '064.pdf', '065.pdf', '066.pdf', '067.pdf', '068.pdf', '069.pdf', '070.pdf', '071.pdf', '072.pdf', '073.pdf', '074.pdf', '075.pdf', '076.pdf', '077.pdf', '078.pdf', '079.pdf', '080.pdf', '081.pdf', '082.pdf', '083.pdf', '084.pdf', '085.pdf', '086.pdf', '087.pdf', '088.pdf', '089.pdf', '090.pdf', '091.pdf', '092.pdf', '093.pdf', '094.pdf', '095.pdf', '096.pdf', '097.pdf', '098.pdf', '099.pdf', '100.pdf', '101.pdf', '102.pdf', '103.pdf', '104.pdf', '105.pdf', '106.pdf', '107.pdf', '108.pdf', '109.pdf', '110.pdf', '111.pdf', '112.pdf', '113.pdf', '114.pdf', '115.pdf', '116.pdf', '117.pdf', '118.pdf', '119.pdf', '120.pdf', '121.pdf', '122.pdf', '123.pdf', '124.pdf', '125.pdf', '126.pdf', '127.pdf', '128.pdf', '129.pdf', '130.pdf', '131.pdf', '132.pdf', '133.pdf', '134.pdf', '135.pdf', '136.pdf', '137.pdf', '138.pdf', '139.pdf', '140.pdf', '141.pdf', '142.pdf', '143.pdf', '144.pdf', '145.pdf', '146.pdf', '147.pdf', '148.pdf', '149.pdf', '150.pdf', '151.pdf', '152.pdf', '153.pdf', '154.pdf', '155.pdf', '156.pdf', '157.pdf', '158.pdf', '159.pdf', '160.pdf', '161.pdf', '162.pdf', '163.pdf', '164.pdf', '165.pdf', '166.pdf', '167.pdf', '168.pdf', '169.pdf', '170.pdf', '171.pdf', '172.pdf', '173.pdf', '174.pdf', '175.pdf', '176.pdf', '177.pdf', '178.pdf', '179.pdf', '180.pdf', '181.pdf', '182.pdf', '183.pdf', '184.pdf', '185.pdf', '186.pdf', '187.pdf', '188.pdf', '189.pdf', '190.pdf', '191.pdf', '192.pdf', '193.pdf', '194.pdf', '195.pdf', '196.pdf', '197.pdf', '198.pdf', '199.pdf']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `format()` on each of your integers. Example:

```
final_list = [format(x, '03') + string for x in numrange]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code I just changed the final_list to include some conditional statements in it.  It loops through the numrange from 1 to 499.  Digits which only have the ones place occupied will have a "00" string attached, because int(x)//10-where x is a number from 1 to 9-evaluates to 0, which is < 1.  You can check this by doing print(1//10), for example.  Then, numbers from 10 to 99 pass the second condition ("0" + str(x) + string if int(x)//10 >= 1 and int(x)//10 < 10).  If you do int(x)//10 for an integer x that is >= 100 the expression will give an int >= 10, which makes the third condition (str(x) + string) true.  Lastly, // is floor division operator in Python that results into an unrounded whole number.

```
    string=".pdf"
    max_num = 500
    numrange = range(1,max_num)
    final_list = ["00" + str(x) + string if int(x)//10 < 1 else "0" + str(x) + 
    string if int(x)//10 >= 1 and int(x)//10 < 10 else str(x) + string for x in numrange]
    print(final_list)
```